# Match only full words using str.match()

Tags: javascript

I need to match a string with given string.

For example:

```
str1 = "how you";
str2 = "How are you";
//I'll split str2 for regex

str1.match(/How|are|you/gi);
```

it will result array of 2 items `how` and `you`. It is fine and that's what I need. But problem is here:

```
str1 = "thanks";
str2 = "Im a boy";
//I'll split str2 for regex

str1.match(/Im|a|boy/gi);
```

It results array of one item that is `a` because it exists in *thanks*. I want an array of 0 items for this. But I don't want to match each letter itself. I want to match word as a whole.

Number of words in str1 and str2 will vary a lot.

Is there any way I can fix this particular code to work accordingly?

Comment: Would word boundaries help? `/\b(Im|a|boy)\b/`?

Comment: Does the order of words matter?

Comment: word boundaries?

Comment: a quick (and dirty) solution would be just add spaces around your "a" in the regex

Comment: @EliteDaMyth there would be thousands of strings like that, so won't prefer to do it

Comment: @HassanImam I just need match counts, array could return matches in any order

Comment: if i were you, i wouldnt use regex for this specific task, i would split str2 and str1, and map to check if the word exists in the array of str1

Comment: @evolutionxbox it worked on 2-3 examples I tried, but not sure if it will work always when both strings will have different kinds of words each with different number of words

Comment: @Vikas What do you mean? The suggestion I gave will match the words `Im`, `a`, or `boy`. Is that not what you wanted?

Comment: @evolutionxbox yes it worked just tested. But can I trust it for many more strings? I'll use it in a chat bot where there will be huge messages.

Comment: if you could explain how it works in the answer, maybe i can evaluate if it works for me or not

Comment: Here's a visual explanation of how it works: https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5Cb(Im%7Ca%7Cboy)%5Cb

Comment: I'm having a hard time understanding it :(

Comment: @Vikas Which part?

Comment: I don't understand how to visualize it on that site. I also read some answers on stackoverlow about /b but couldn't understant. But I think i'll learn with some time

Comment: https://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html might be of help?

Comment: I'm just going through it

Comment: @evolutionxbox I got a bit idea about it.

Comment: @evolutionxbox I tried \b in my actual code but it's not working, because I think slash is messing up. I can't even escape it in the regex string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not a regex based solution, but is probably faster (and better) to do it this way.

```js
str1 = "how you";
arr1 = str1.toLowerCase().split(" ")
str2 = "How are you";
arr2 = str2.toLowerCase().split(" ")

matches = arr2.filter(word => arr1.includes(word))
```

Comment: While the \b method of regex works for me, I'm still accepting your answer since you've put effort. I'll try it in case regex causes some problems.